# How to programmatically call Advanced Application Restart on App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I want to execute Advanced Application restart periodically and I want to find a way to do it programmatically.

Here on the screen, I have just a single instance, but in another environment there are several, and this is why I want to do it via Advanced Application restart.

[image]

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/restart) as reference for REST API call to restart app service.

But if you want to be very specific like in Advanced tool you need to drill a bit deeper:

1. Get your instance from the list:

   GET
   https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourceGroups/<resourcegroup_name>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<rappservice_name>/instances?api-version=2020-12-01
2. Once you have Instance get your process:

   GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourceGroups/<resourcegroup_name>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<rappservice_name>/<instance_id>/processes?api-version=2020-12-01
3. Stop process:

   POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourceGroups/<resourcegroup_name>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<appservice_name>/<instance_id>/processes/<process_id>/stop?api-version=2020-12-01

I used [Azure Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com/) to figure out single calls based on windows app service.

Comment: Might be a silly question, but if I stop a process, do I need to start it again? How it is different from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/app-service-plans/reboot-worker ?